# Can't set the Google key in Unity Editor for In-app Purchases on project settings page with projects created after 6/22/2022

Tags: unity-game-engine, key

I created a new project in Unity 2022.1.3f1 and attempted to do In-app Purchases with the new Unity Games Services package In App Purchases 4.1.5 and on the Project Settings window I get the errors "There was an error checking the server for existing key. please try again later." and "Please enter your Google Public Key for this application to ensure revenue numbers reflect verified payment for Google":[image]

I then attempted to set the Google key and got the message, "You are not authorized to set the license key":

[image]

So the question is: how do I get authorized to set the key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple: You don't! The error message is a red herring (NPI)! Just ignore this error and add the key to Unity's Developer Dashboard from the projects tab and project settings:

[image]

Happy programming!

Comment: In my Unity Developer's Dashboard for my project, the Google License Key is blank. I had just updated to the latest Purchasing Package (4.5.0) in my Unity editor, but have no Google Public Key which is being requested. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

In the latest IAP unity package (4.5.x), there should be a menu item in the editor to set the Google Licence key:
Copy paste the key in the popup that appears, and click generate key.

[image]

Comment: This answer corrected! After press the button Obfuscate... Just copy and paste google public key and press verify

Answer (score 0):

I can't configure the in app purchases without having this set up in the editor. It is already applies in the dashboard, but it doesn't carry over. The fix of enabling analytics doesn't work as it's not available anymore in 2022

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer, it is a comment.